# Access ansible.cfg variable in task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How can I refer `remote_tmp` (or any other) value defined in `ansible.cfg` in my tasks? For example, in the `my_task/defaults/main.yml`:

```
file_ver: "1.5"
deb_file: "{{ defaults.remote_tmp }}/deb_file_{{ file_ver }}.deb"
```

produces an error:

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, 
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, 
            which appears to include a variable that is undefined. 
            The error was: {{ defaults.remote_tmp }}/deb_file_{{ file_ver }}.deb: 
           'defaults' is undefined\... }
```

Comment: have you tried just `{{ remote_tmp }}`?

Comment: @sircapsalot, of course, `'remote_tmp' is undefined`.

Comment: this leads me to believe that the `ansible.cfg` file is not properly being read.  where is your cfg file? project root?

Comment: @sircapsalot, I have my own `ansible.cfg` located in the root of my project dir with only one entry `[defaults]\nroles_path = /home/deploy/devops/ansible/roles`.

Comment: this might have something to do with you putting a custom variable inside of `[default]`.  according to [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#configuration-file), it states "In the [defaults] secton of ansible.cfg, the following settings are tunable."  this statement leads me to believe that it only reads specific values under `[default]`

Comment: @sircapsalot, but both `roles_path` and `remote_tmp` are ansible's standard params.

Comment: oh, my mistake. you're right.  if i notice something, i'll let you know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box.
You either need action plugin or vars plugin to read different configuration parameters.
If you go action plugin way, you'll have to call your newly created action to get `remote_tmp` defined.
If you choose vars plugin way, `remote_tmp` is defined with other host vars during inventory initialization.

Example `./vars_plugins/tmp_dir.py`:

```
from ansible import constants as C

class VarsModule(object):

    def __init__(self, inventory):
        pass

    def run(self, host, vault_password=None):
        return dict(remote_tmp = C.DEFAULT_REMOTE_TMP)
```

Note that `vars_plugins` folder should be near your `hosts` file or you should explicitly define it in your ansible.cfg.

You can now test it with:

```
$ ansible localhost -i hosts -m debug -a "var=remote_tmp"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "remote_tmp": "$HOME/.ansible/tmp"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lookup`.

```
file_ver: "1.5"
deb_file: "{{ lookup('ini', 'remote_tmp section=defaults file=ansible.cfg' }}/deb_file_{{ file_ver }}.deb"
```

**EDIT**

In case you don't know the path to the configuration file, you can set that to a fact by running the following tasks.

```
- name: look for ansible.cfg, see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html
  local_action: stat path={{ item }}
  register: ansible_cfg_stat
  when: (item | length) and not (ansible_cfg_stat is defined and ansible_cfg_stat.stat.exists)
  with_items:
    - "{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_CONFIG') }}"
    - ansible.cfg
    - "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/.ansible.cfg"
    - /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

- name: set fact for later use
  set_fact:
    ansible_cfg: "{{ item.item }}"
  when: item.stat is defined and item.stat.exists
  with_items: "{{ ansible_cfg_stat.results }}"
```

You can then write:

```
file_ver: "1.5"
deb_file: "{{ lookup('ini', 'remote_tmp section=defaults file=' + ansible_cfg) }}/deb_file_{{ file_ver }}.deb"
```

Comment: And what if `ansible.cfg` is not in the current directory?

Comment: Ivan wrote that "I have my own ansible.cfg located in the root of my project dir", and this works in that situation.

Comment: I updated my answer so that it works with any `ansible.cfg` location.

Comment: It's not a very reliable method. It will fail in some configurations (macOS with Homebrew-installed Python, likely some Python virtualenvs). One way to determine the config file used would be to run `ansible-playbook --version` and parse the output. Still it might not give the same result as for the current process. On top of that, this will fail if the setting was not there.