# How to overwrite a default variable in ansible.cfg dynamically?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook with the following task that must copy the 2 Gb file from local to remote servers and extract files:

```
- name: Copy archived file to target server and extract 
  unarchive:
    src: /path_to_source_dir/file.tar.gz  
    dest: /path_to_dest_dir
```

This task fails because ansible copies file to **/home** mount point on the target server and there's not enough space there:

```
sftp> put /path_to_source_dir/file.tar.gz /home/my_user_name/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1551129648.53-14181330218552/source  
scp: /home/my_user_name/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1551129648.53-14181330218552/source: No space left on device
```

The reason for that is because **ansible.cfg** has a default parameter:

```
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
```

How to overwrite this parameter from the playbook (if possible) and make ansible to copy file to the same destination directory specified in the task? So it would be like this:

```
remote_tmp = /path_to_dest_dir/.ansible/tmp
```

And the destination path is going to be different each time for a different target server!

Cleaning **/home** is not an option for me. 
The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246768/access-ansible-cfg-variable-in-task) unfortunately is not very clear to me.

Comment: You can use `ansible_remote_tmp` in your inventory file or group_vars directory to specify `remote_tmp` for a specific host or host group ([more info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#running-on-solaris)).

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to achieve what you are looking to do. Which one is a matter of preference and your use case.

You found the first way, setting an environment variable before running the playbook. Great for a quick on-the-fly job. Remembering to do that every time you run a certain playbook is indeed annoying.  A slight variation of that is to use the `environment` keyword to set that variable for the play. You can also set environment variable in a role, block or a single task. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html?highlight=environment%20directive. Here is an example of it in use: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html?highlight=environment.

Using the environment keyword in a play et al works well for a specific application of automation, but what if you want Ansible to always use a different remote tmp path for specific servers? Like all variables, the `remote_tmp` can be sourced from inventory host and group variables not just the config file or environment variables. You need to mind you variable precedence if it is being set in different places. With this you could set `remote_tmp` in your inventory for that host or a group of hosts. Ansible will always use that path for that host or hosts in that group without having to define it in every play or roles. If you need to change that path, you change it in your inventory and it changes the behavior for all playbook runs without any additional edits.  Here is an example of it being used as a host variable in static inventory: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html?highlight=remote_tmp#running-on-solaris

So while the specific issue of "dynamically" setting the remote tmp directory on a host is not a best practice topic per se, it does become an example of the best practice of making the most of variables in Ansible.

For reference, remote temporary directories are handled by the shell plugins. While many parameters are shared, there are others that are specific to the shell Ansible using. Ansible uses `sh` by default. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html

Hope that helps. Happy automating.